# update maker location on Mapbox js using mysql and ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

After hours of searching I have finally got markers on my map from MySQL. the last part im struggling with is how to move the makers once the data is changed in MySQL.

currently I have.

```
function loadMarkers() {
            $.get('ajax-get-markers.php', function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data)
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(data, function(d){
            console.log(d.lng, d.lat);
                // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
                var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat({lng: d.lng ,lat: d.lat})
                    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup()
                    .setHTML("<h3>" + d.name+ "</h3>"))
                    .addTo(map);
            });
            console.log(currentMarkers)
            })
        }
setInterval(loadMarkers, 5000)
    </script>
```

I have realized this just drops a marker on top of itself each call.
one option I have is to remove all the markers and re-add them but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep track of the markers that exist. For example you could create an array that holds the marker objects.

```js
marker[i] = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat({lng: d.lng ,lat: d.lat})
                    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup()
                    .setHTML("<h3>" + d.name+ "</h3>"))
                    .addTo(map);
```

You can also change the markers location after they were added to the map by using

`marker[i].setLngLat({lng: d.lng ,lat: d.lat})`

Comment: If I created a new function called updateMaker and made that one have the setInterval, I would use `marker[i].setLngLat({lng: d.lng ,lat: d.lat})` would it need a foreach loop and a referance?